# How various 'Kavach Stotras' from Hindu Puranas can protect women from suffering molestation and other severe crimes?

Tags: mantras, women, stotra, spirituality

We come across various Kavachas or Armours of deities which claim that the one who reads them will be protected. 
Nowadays we see the crimes against women are ever increasing.  Isn't it the right time to test these scriptures? I feel we must print these kavachas and distribute them to various women activists and women welfare groups. Is it practical? How can we who love Hinduism and aware of it's glory save women from the horrible sufferings of brutal crimes happening these days?

Comment: Probably they will.. because in Kavachas the deities are requested to protect various body parts of the chanter.. So let them try and see the results for themselves..

Comment: Very good Q and thought. I'd like to know the answer too. However, I do know that women do not have adhikara to chant many kavachas. They may chant raksha stotrams, chant rama nama ,tulasi kavacham. Again, bravo. Let's reopen.

Comment: Women do possess right to read kavachas. In fact the Hanuman Kavach was written and then taught to Seeta by Rama. There is Narayan Kavach in which various Avataras of lord Vishnu are requested to protect the devotee. If women start reciting any of the  Kavachas like Hanuman Kavacha, they might get protected by it's positive and protective effect. Not necessary that lord Hanuman will come personally to save the woman devotee but something will happen and the devotee will be saved. The problem is that most of the Hindu people do not beleive in power of scriptures, due to mostly ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kavachas are special kind of stotras or hymns in tantric tradition which have a specific purpose of protection.

It is for everyone not only for women or men. It is a great way to protect oneself from negative forces.

[Devi kavacham](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Devi_Kavacham) of durga sapta shati is a very famous among the kavachas. Apart from this there are many other kavachas. Also there are kavachas related to vaishnava deities like sudarshana kavacha, narayana kavacha etc.

In kavacha, various organs both physical and astral body and mind are being protected by various deities. It is adviced that one should generally chant the kavachas for overall.protection once a day.

Apart from kavachas there are also hymns called hridayam which are also useful along with kavachas for nourishment.

Comment: Good answer. :) I have heard that Durga Saptashati is Kilit by Lord Shankara to prevent one from misusing it.

Comment: @Deepeshkumar but this stotra is not core part of the sapta shati and its for protection so.cant be misused. You can do it along with stotras such as Aditya hridayam.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we should be distributing the scriptures to men,

> The daughter, O king, has been ordained in the scriptures to be equal to the son.

—Mahabharata 13.47.26

> Where women are worshipped, there the Gods are delighted. But where they are not worshipped, all religious ceremonies become futile.

—Mahabharata 13.45.5

> If a man has intercourse with an unmarried woman, **who consents to it**, it is no offense, but he shall deck her with ornaments, worship her, and thus bring her to his house as his bride.

—Nāradasmṛti 13.71-72

Comment: That was a nice suggestion. But I am specifically talking about use of Kavachas to protect women from undergoing heinous crimes.